# Is there a way to read audio file preferably WAV file, as byte array in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to work on audio files, specifically WAV files, but I am completely clueless about it I have tried several packages alike to [assets_audio_player](https://flutterawesome.com/play-music-audio-stored-in-assets-files-directly-from-flutter/). I need to load the file and as an array of float values.

Comment: you looking for this? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-io/File/readAsBytes.html

Comment: Yes, this will work! thank you @ShubhamSrivastava

Comment: @HarshitVavaiya Could you provide a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final audio = await _getAudioContent();

Future<List<int>> _getAudioContent() async {

    final path = 'path to the wav file';
    return File(path).readAsBytesSync().toList();
  }
```